# Question over cosets and Cayley tables

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be the group of integers and $H$ the subgroup consisting of all multiples of 3. $H$ is obviously a subgroup. Its also obvious (slightly) that $H$ is normal since $G$ is abelian.

What would the 3 left cosets of $H$ in $G$ be? What is the Cayley table for the group $G/H$?

Comment: Do you know about congruence of integers?

Comment: Congruence, as in modulo?

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean.

Comment: One or twice you might have encountered the notation $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ for the integers modulo $3$. This notation is *not* coincidental. =)

Comment: Quotient groups are just a generalisation of modular arithmetic (or modular arithmetic is a specific case of quotient groups). You are left with three cosets: $[0] = {0, 3, 6, ...}; [1] = {1, 4, 7,...}; [2] = {2, 5, 8,...}$ and note that $G/H = \text{set of all left cosets}$ and $|G/H| = 3$. What then must $G/H$ be isomorphic to?

Answer (score 1):

The operation on $\mathbb{Z}$ is addition, so if $H$ is any subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, the set of (left) cosets of $H$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ is $$\{z+H \mid z\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
So, let's compute the members of that set for $$H=3\mathbb{Z}=\{\ldots, -9, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9, \ldots\}$$  First, let's consider $z=0$, since that's as good of a place to start as anywhere. $$\begin{eqnarray*}
0+3\mathbb{Z}&=&\{\ldots, 0-9, 0-6, 0-3, 0+0, 0+3, 0+6, 0+9, \ldots\}\\
&=&\{\ldots, -9, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9, \ldots\}
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Next, let's compute $z=1$.
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
1+3\mathbb{Z}&=&\{\ldots, 1-9, 1-6, 1-3, 1+0, 1+3, 1+6, 1+9, \ldots\}\\
&=&\{\ldots, -8, -5, -2, 1, 4, 7, 10, \ldots\}
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Next is $z=2$.
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
2+3\mathbb{Z}&=&\{\ldots, 2-9, 2-6, 2-3, 2+0, 2+3, 2+6, 2+9, \ldots\}\\
&=&\{\ldots, -7, -4, -1, 2, 5, 8, 11, \ldots\}
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Now, what about $z=3$?
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
3+3\mathbb{Z}&=&\{\ldots, 3-9, 3-6, 3-3, 3+0, 3+3, 3+6, 3+9, \ldots\}\\
&=&\{\ldots, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, \ldots\}\\
&=&\{\ldots, -9,-6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9, \ldots\}\\
&=&0+3\mathbb{Z}
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Interesting: we've arrived at the same coset, $0+3\mathbb{Z}=3+3\mathbb{Z}$.  Can you figure out how $4+3\mathbb{Z}$ and $5+3\mathbb{Z}$ would turn out?  Can you generalize that?

Next, to compute the Cayley table, you can use the following rule to shorten your work: $$(a+3\mathbb{Z})+(b+3\mathbb{Z})=(a+b)+3\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: An alternative way of computing the Cayley table is to start with a $3\times3$ grid and fill it in. There is a unique way of doing this.

Comment: @user1729 This is true. I gave a canonical answer so that the user can practice a direct proof for the cases when that doesn't work. (To OP: I suggest you try user1729's method, then see if you can come up with necessary and sufficient conditions on the group for which this works.)